# Do NY travel restrictions apply every time?

Tags: new-york-state, travel

Wondering about the NY travel restrictions: if I were to complete the self-quarantine requirement etc, and then leave NY (to a place very nearby, Jersey City NJ) and come back to NY the next day, would I be required to go through the quarantine process again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will not be required to quarantine.  The quarantine requirement only applies to travelers arriving from non-contiguous states (i.e., states not bordering New York).  From the detailed [guidance for quarantine restrictions](https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2020/11/interm_guidance_travel_advisory.pdf), as of November 3, 2020:

> ### Quarantine Criteria for Travel
>
> All travelers entering New York from a state that is not a contiguous state, or from a CDC Level 2 or 3 Travel Health Notice country, shall quarantine for a period of 14 days, consistent with Department of Health regulations for quarantine, unless:
>
> 1. For travelers who traveled outside of New York for more than 24 hours, such travelers must obtain testing within 72 hours prior to arrival in New York, AND
> 2. Such travelers must, upon arrival in New York, quarantine according to Department of Health guidelines, for a minimum of three days, measured from time of arrival, and on day 4 may seek a diagnostic test to exit quarantine.
>
> For travelers that meet the criteria above, the traveler may exit quarantine upon receipt of the second negative test result.
>
> **Contiguous states are Pennsylvania, New Jersey, Connecticut, Massachusetts and Vermont. Travelers from these states are not subject to this guidance.**
>
> Travelers who leave New York State for less than 24 hours do not need to obtain a diagnostic test before departing and do not need to quarantine upon return. However, such travelers must fill out the traveler form upon entry and must obtain a diagnostic test on the fourth day after arrival in New York.

(bolding mine)

Comment: Thanks! You also cleared up another misconception I was apparently under. I thought the quarantine was only 3 days long for anyone and that the 14-day quarantine was outdated, but now I see that it's 3 days for New York residents who traveled outside and 14 for residents of non-contiguous states.

Comment: @Yujiri: I don't think it's actually residence-based;  so far as I can tell, anyone can go through the two-test process to exit quarantine early.